# EF relation in constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I get error;

> Cannot implicitly convert type Sale in ICollection

when I do this, I have seen it in some examples and it is possible to do so.

```
Sale sale= new Sale(){ Id = 1 };
Service service = new Service() { Name= "SomeService",Sales=sale}; //I can't assign sale


public class Service: EntityBase
{
    //public Service()
    //{
    //    Sales= new HashSet<Sale>();
    //}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales{ get; set; }
}
```

How can i solve it? 
I don't want to do: `service.Sales.add(fact)`, if there is another way

Comment: IMO the Exception message is very self explanatory.

Comment: Yes I know, but it's not possible assign like this? 
new Service() { Name= "SomeService",Sales=sale}

Comment: No, that would completely break type safety. If you could do that then you could assign an `int` to a `string` reference or a `HashSet` to a `DateTime`, the fact that you can't do this is called Type Safety which is checked at compile time and is a good thing. Lets assume you could do this (*and you could with some bad casting*), you would get a run time `NRE` (*or invalid cast exception, at some point*) because a `Collection<Sale>` and `Sale` are not the same thing.

Comment: You are trying to treat `ICollection<Sale>` and `Sale` as same types. There are not of same type.. So they are not compatible.. The below answers points you in the right direction.

Comment: like this https://danielggarcia.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/entity-framework-iii-select-insert-update-delete/

LineaPedido lp = new LineaPedido() {
    Pedido = p,
    Producto = dbContext.Productos.Where(prod => prod.IdProducto == 4).First(),
    Cantidad = 7
};

Comment: @gvivetapplus if you dont want to do `service.Sales.add(fact)` or any of the answers as below. Then you would have to maintain a new private properties of type `ICollection<Sale>` and return that when you access `Sales` and add the item into it when you set value to `Sales`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were very opposed to using `.Add` and wanted to pass one or more `Sale` instances to the `Service` instance and have them added to the `Sales` collection then you could add a second constructor that takes one or more `Sale` instances like so.

```
public class Service: EntityBase
{
    public Service() // empty constructor needed for EF
    {}

    public Service(params Sale[] sales)
    {
      Sales = new List<Sale>(sales);
    }

    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Sale> Sales{ get; set; }
}

// example with 2 sales
Sale sale1 = new Sale(){ Id = 1 };
Sale sale2 = new Sale(){ Id = 2 };
Service service = new Service(sale1,sale2) { Name= "SomeService" };
```

*Leave the empty constructor in place as it is used by EF.*

Answer (score 0):

What you're saying here is that a Sale = List();

make a list of sales, add a sale to it, and then in the constructor say that Sales = the list of sales u made.

```
Sale sale = new Sale(){ Id = 1 };

List<Sale> sales = new List<Sale>();

sales.Add(sale);

Service service = new Service() { Name = "Service", Sales = sales };
```